# Installation of buildpack for MySQL for PHP, create folder/file in root directory (Bluemix)

Tags: php, mysql, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I have two problems with my Bluemix.

I want to use an additional buildpack in order to use php with MySQL. I have chosen [this](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack) one. The push worked fine with the `cf` command line. But when pushing some changes on my php files with source tree to Bluemix, the buildpack gets removed.

**Question #1:** How can I install the buildpack and push normal commits afterwards?

The buildpack requires some changes to use MySQL. I have to create the directory `.bp-config` and a the file `options.json` in it according to this [issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/22).

**Question #2:** How can I create a folder or a file in the root directory of my app?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `.bp-config` directory locally (or in your [DevOps services](https://hub.jazz.net/) repository) and then push these changes to Bluemix. Any further changes also need to be made either locally or in [DevOps services](https://hub.jazz.net/) if you are using that. That code (including config files) is then pushed to Bluemix and your app instance is recreated for you each time from the code present in this new push.

If there are files locally that you don't want to push to Bluemix (i.e. the vendor directory then you can add a `.cfignore` file that works in a similar way to `.gitignore`)

The buildpack is also reinstalled each time you push a change to Bluemix (although it is downloaded from a cache after the first push to save time).